# Can Can.js bind over existing HTML?

Tags: javascript, mvvm

Does anyone know a way of binding a Can.js view over existing HTML?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

James

edit for clarity:

If you ALREADY have a page with HTML in it, the server has already rendered the HTML, is there a way to use Can.js view to simply bind events over the top of that HTML, or do you have to remove that HTML from the DOM and replace it with a fragment that you've just constructed using Can.js??

Comment: Your question is unclear. Perhaps an example and an indication of the reason for the question would help. Certainly a glance at the Can.js documentation shows it using HTML with Mustache templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this, you just need to put can.Control on parent element.

```
new MyControl('.my-selector')
```

Comment: Thanks @WHITECOLOR, I'd misunderstood that bit whilst skim-reading the docs. :) Good knowledge...